# How to use a custom version of one DLL otherwise found in via referenced NuGet package?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, nuget

Cross platform Xamarin Forms project in Visual Studio and Visual Studio for Mac. The project references [Akavache](https://www.nuget.org/packages/akavache/6.0.0-alpha0038). Akavache has a dependency of [akavache.sqlite3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/akavache.sqlite3/). I have made a custom change to a DLL in the akavache.sqlite3 repo and built the DLL locally, and would prefer not to have to switch the whole Akavache package tree over to a custom build for all the Akavache dlls and dependencies. So essentially...would like to continue referencing the NuGet package like normal but "substitute" one DLL on the fly. Or something equivalent like that!

But it needs to be portable too. At first I used a post build copy command to overwrite the "standard" dll that gets put in the TargetDir. That works in the sense that it copies to TargetDir, but for Android copying the DLL into the TargetDir does no good. The DLL is already incorporated into the APK in the TargetDir instead. So it would need to happen some other way. Same basic issue if you used MSBuild instead of a post build command line.

Any thoughts?

FWIW, my current workaround is to copy the DLL over top of the cached NuGet package location. But the problem with this approach is anytime the cache would get cleared/updated it needs to be reapplied. That's also not an obvious step to do, or easily automated, when another developer want to get set up on their machine.

Comment: Prefixing `if exist` would be the trivial solution.

Answer (score 0):

Any `.nupkg` files are just ZIP files with some metadata, so you can change at the contents. The [NuGet Package Explorer](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer) should make it a little easier to view the contents.

The NuGet Gallery (e.g. https://www.nuget.org/) has a "Download" link on the left hand side, otherwise just install the package into an empty project and then take a peek.

Comment: Thx for the thoughts. It's not so much knowing what's in the package, it's coming up with a system to use the custom dll that works across platforms, and doesn't require a lot of special setup on different development machines. I'll update the post with my current workaround for more info.